# Token is not getting a value when the form sent by email

Tags: content-management-system, workflow, orchardcms

I'm developing a basic recruitment-type website.
I have an "Apply" CustomForm attached with a contenttype("Job"), but I can't get access fields outside of the CustomForm widget. I'm trying to add the reference number or the url to the email within the workflow. Orchard shows {Content.Fields.Input-Reference} token, but it returns no value when used.

Should I overwrite the handler when the form is created or how can I access fields of other zones?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you don't actually need to add a custom token to your module. Custom Forms module takes care of that for you and adds the tokens for fields itself. You just need to use them in the email module.

Just look for a tokens named like this:

Content.Fields.[FormContentTypeName].[FieldName]

Not that the tasks of adding custom tokens to the system and accessing them inside the workflow are particularly hard, mind you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a good 40 tokens shown by Orchard but most of them doesn't actually pick up a thing. I don't really understand why they are offered at all. Do you know is there a way I can access the returnUrl value somehow or access any unique values of page?